# Filter in Google Sheets not working within IF statement mismatched range sizes

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, nested-if

I am receiving the following error:

FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1759. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

The function in question is:

```
=IF(F2="",
    "Please enter a year",
    IF(F4="",
       IF(F6="",
          {"Same filter that built SrcTbl"},
          FILTER(SrcTbl,SrcCat=F6)),
       IF(F6="",
          FILTER(SrcTbl,MONTH(SrcDates)=MONTH(F4&1)),
          FILTER(SrcTbl,MONTH(SrcDates)=MONTH(F4&1),SrcCat=F6))))
```

SrcCat is a column within SrcTbl (e.g. A:A vs. A:C). The cells being checked contain a Year, a Month (or no month), and a Category (or no category). All of the filter functions work properly on their own, provided the respective cells are populated, and the function works properly if I replace the faulty filters (both containing SrcCat=F6) with a text string. It is only when a value is placed in F6 that the nested filters return this error.

Why do these filters work on their own, but not when inside this function?

Comment: As a recommendation try to always include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yf7bb_uG86tjPzC9-b0VcJckDVtFQY1EEQuiZCUwaLg/edit?usp=sharing This is the behavior I'm expecting.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y0UoiWNKRY1xJKK80Naw-QzlVK8IgR_SkJYTIPhpXls/edit?usp=sharing Works the way I expect if I remove all the data and use filler data. Unfortunately, I'd rather not share live data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of your:

```
={FILTER(CData,  YEAR(CDates) =B1);
  FILTER(SData,  YEAR(SDates) =B1);
  FILTER(CrData, YEAR(CrDates)=B1)}
```

you can do just:

```
=FILTER({CData; SData; CrData}, YEAR({CDates; SDates; CrDates})=B1)
```

now what went wrong:

[image]

Comment: Oh that is so much cleaner! I'll try to remember that in the future. Yeah, still not sure why it works in my second example but not my actual spreadsheet, as the logic is the same. I've decided I can live with just filtering on the year and category leaving it at that. Thanks!